# npm install bcrypt 環境 surface pro2(windows8.1)　でエラー。

Tags: npm, node.js

windows8.1環境で、node.js sailsを触っていました。
参考サイトを元に認証処理を実装していましたが、bcryptという認証モジュールがないため、npm install bcryptを実行しました（当方Git Shellを使用して、PowerShell上で作業を実行しています）。

最初はpythonがversion3.0超えだったためエラーでとまりました。
アンインストールし、pythonサイトから直接python2.7をダウンロード→インストールし、そこは解決しました。
また、node-gypもnpmでinstallしました。

ここまでで、エラー内容は変わったのですが、以前エラーです。
以下のサイト（英語）でも同様のエラーがでているとの報告がでていますが、
解決まで至っていない模様。Windows8環境では難しいのでしょうか？
dockerでcentos環境を構築して、その中でやったほうが賢いでしょうかね。。。

https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/issues/255

Comment: エラーの詳細を載せると回答者の参考になると思います。また、node.jsのバージョン情報など、環境情報の詳細も記載すると良いと思います。

Comment: bomber さん　早速回答ありがとうございました。
早速参考に、linkのPython2.7コンパイラのDL VC2008を環境にいれるためVisualStudioExpress2008VCをインストールなどしました。
が、私の環境ではうまくいかないようでエラー内容は変わりませんでした。
そこで、目先を変えたところ、bcrypt-nodejsというモジュールがみつかったため、require 'bcrypt-nodejs'で解決！でした。
もやもやは微妙に残りましたが。これで良子とします。

ご協力ありがとうございました。

Comment: bomberさんへのコメントは回答に対するコメントの方が望ましいです。

Comment: bomberさんのとは違うやり方で解決したのでしたら、別の回答として投稿してしまってよいと思います。その方が後から検索した場合に解決策・回避策が分かりやすいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

はじめまして。
エラーがわかりませんが、私の環境では最終的に以下の様になりインストールに成功したように見えます。

**追記**

すみません、環境を書き忘れてました。

OSはWindows 8.1 pro, (powershellではなく)コマンドプロンプトから行いました。

---

```
M:\bcrypt>npm list
M:\bcrypt
└─┬ bcrypt@0.8.0
  ├── bindings@1.0.0
  └── nan@1.3.0
```

pythonとnpmのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
M:\bcrypt>python -V
Python 2.7.8

M:\bcrypt>npm -v
1.4.28
```

途中でpython 2.7が求められたということで気になったのは、VCのバージョンはなんでしょうか？
Windows上でpython 2.7モジュールのCのソースをコンパイルするにはVC 2008のコンパイラが必要になります。

現在ではMicrosoftから [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

が提供されていますので、pythonモジュールのCコンパイルが原因であれば、こちらを導入してみると結果が変わるかもしれません。

(あと私の環境にはVisual Studio 2013も入っています。)

以下はインストール時の全ログです。

```
M:\bcrypt>npm install bcrypt
\
> bcrypt@0.8.0 install M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
このソリューション内のプロジェクトを 1 度に 1 つずつビルドします。並行ビルドを有効にするには、"/m" スイッチを追加してください。
  blowfish.cc
  bcrypt.cc
  bcrypt_node.cc
..\src\bcrypt.cc(232): warning C4267: '=' : 'size_t' から 'unsigned char' に変換しました。データが失われているかもしれません。 [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\bu
ild\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xlocale(337): warning C4530: C++ 例外処理を使っていますが、アンワインド セマンティクスは有効には
なりません。/EHsc を指定してください。 (..\src\
bcrypt_node.cc) [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1221): warning C4267: '引数' : 'size_t' から 'int' に変換しました。データが失われているかもしれません。 (..
\src\bcrypt_node.cc) [M:\bcry
pt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1247): warning C4267: '引数' : 'size_t' から 'int' に変換しました。データが失われているかもしれません。 (..
\src\bcrypt_node.cc) [M:\bcry
pt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(106): warning C4244: '引数' : 'ssize_t' から 'unsigned char' への変換です。データが失われる可能性があります。 [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcry
pt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj
]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(167): warning C4244: '引数' : 'const ssize_t' から 'unsigned char' への変換です。データが失われる可能性があります。 [M:\bcrypt\node_module
s\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.v
cxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(261): warning C4267: '初期化中' : 'size_t' から 'int' に変換しました。データが失われているかもしれません。 [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\
build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
..\src\bcrypt_node.cc(262): warning C4267: '初期化中' : 'size_t' から 'int' に変換しました。データが失われているかもしれません。 [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\
build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
C:\Users\UserName\.node-gyp\0.10.32\deps\v8\include\v8.h(179): warning C4506: インライン関数 'v8::Persistent<v8::Object> v8::Persistent<v8::Object>::New(v8::Han
dle<v8
::Object>)' は定義されていません。 (..\src\bcrypt_node.cc) [M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
     ライブラリ M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.lib とオブジェクト M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.exp を作成中
  コード生成しています。
  コード生成が終了しました。
  bcrypt_lib.vcxproj -> M:\bcrypt\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\\bcrypt_lib.node
bcrypt@0.8.0 node_modules\bcrypt
├── bindings@1.0.0
└── nan@1.3.0

M:\bcrypt>
```